# ... As likely to ... as

Tags: grammar

I am a student of English as Second Language.

I would like to know which expression I can use to talk about a changeable or variable situation/person.

I will try to make myself understood with an example. Mary is laughing out loud now but three minutes later she might start crying.

Is it correct to say: "Mary is as likely to laugh as to cry"?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Noemi, please, see our sister site specifically tailored for ESL students, and do not esitate to ask: ell.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, as long as you think the probability is more or less even. That's the way equative constructions like this work; they're parallel, and the comparison (here _Mary is likely_) appears only in the first _as_ clause, though it can also appear in both places: _Mary is as likely to laugh as she is likely to cry_.

Answer (score 3):

In the situation you provided, I would not use that phrase construction, "As likely to ... as ...," because it usually implies equal chance of two reactions in response to to a single event.

For example, say Mary sees a particularly embarrassing moment from a childhood video; in that situation she might be "as likely to laugh as to cry." However, if she expresses two responses one after the other--if at first she starts to laugh and *later* begins to cry--then her response is not related to the likelihood of one event compared to another.

The answer to your question really depends on the meaning of "changeable" or "variable". If you mean variable in a temporal sense (that is to say, that the reaction changes in time), that the person's reaction could change, then the phrase does not apply.

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter) but I would say that if Mary is a very emotional person with mercurial mood swings, then the phrase, *"Mary is as likely to laugh as to cry."* is viable.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried to phrase this in simple English for Noemi, but perhaps I failed to describe it well enough in that effort.

In the example you provided, involving mercurial mood swings, yes the phrase could apply. However I would still feel uneasy using this construction, because it has a heavy "either/or" connotation. Either Mary will laugh, or she will cry (with more or less equal probability, sure). If somebody told me that Mary laughed for three minutes and then began to cry, I would not ascribe her reaction to that situation with the phrase "as likely to laugh as to cry".